# Django: How to create one Class Based view with two models which have one-to-many relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, backend

I want users be able to create a post with multiple images (that's why I have separate models). How am  I able to do that using class based views and one template?

**models.py**

```py
class UserPost(models.Model):
     title=models.CharField(max_length=255)
     text=models.TextField()

class Image(models.Model):
     user_post = models.ForeignKey(UserPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is struggling with this, I solved it this way.

**forms.py**

```
class UploadPostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=myModels.UserPost
        fields=['title','text','category','is_used','price']

class UploadImages(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=myModels.Image
        fields=['image']
```

**views.py**

```
class CompletePost(LoginRequiredMixin,View):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    post_form=myForms.UploadPostForm()
    image_form=myForms.UploadImages()
    return render(request,'shop/create_post.html',{'post_form':post_form,'image_form':image_form})
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    post_form=myForms.UploadPostForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    image_form=myForms.UploadImages(request.POST)
    if post_form.is_valid() and image_form.is_valid():
        user_post_v=post_form.save(commit=False)
        images=image_form.save(commit=False)
        user_post_v.user_id = self.request.user
        user_post_v.save()
        for image in request.FILES.getlist('image'):
            image_obj = shopModels.Image()
            image_obj.user_post = user_post_v
            image_obj.image = image
            image_obj.save()
        transaction.commit()
        return redirect('home')
```